# Joining two columns from single table with 'OR' is too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch total transaction count and amounts from last-day of previous month to last-day of current month *(time is '15:00:00')*.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE mjr_agent
(
    id bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    head_agent_id varchar(20),
    code varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    agent_type smallint NOT NULL,
    agent_group smallint NOT NULL,
    division varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    township varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    shop_name varchar(200),
    contact_name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    ph_no varchar(50),
    contact_ph_no varchar(50),
    address varchar(500),
    record_reg_id bigint NOT NULL,
    record_upd_id bigint NOT NULL,
    record_reg_date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    record_upd_date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE mjr_transaction_item
(
    id bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    exl_id bigint NOT NULL,
    sr_no int NOT NULL,
    txn_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    txn_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    txn_status smallint NOT NULL,
    src_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    src_type smallint NOT NULL,
    src_name varchar(100),
    src_ocpt varchar(100),
    dest_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    dest_type smallint NOT NULL,
    dest_name varchar(100),
    desc_ocpt varchar(100),
    amount numeric,
    reason varchar(250),
    medium smallint NOT NULL,
    record_reg_id bigint NOT NULL,
    record_upd_id bigint NOT NULL,
    record_reg_date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    record_upd_date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

**Total records in each table**

mjr_agent = 700 and mjr_transaction_item = 1136043

**Query**

```
SELECT
    agnt.ID AS agent_id,
    COUNT ( DISTINCT txi.ID ) AS total_transaction,
    SUM ( txi.amount ) AS total_amount
FROM
    mjr_agent agnt
    LEFT JOIN mjr_transaction_item txi ON agnt.code = txi.src_id 
    OR agnt.code = txi.dest_id
WHERE
    CONCAT (( date_trunc( 'month', to_timestamp( '2019-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day' ) :: DATE, ' 15:00:00' ) :: TIMESTAMP >= txi.txn_date 
    AND txi.txn_date >= CONCAT (( date_trunc( 'month', to_timestamp( '2019-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )) :: DATE - 1 ), ' 15:00:00' ) :: TIMESTAMP 
GROUP BY
    agnt.ID
```

**Query Plan**

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.27..52530.69 rows=86 width=48) (actual time=779.221..14716.528 rows=400 loops=1)
  Group Key: agnt.id
  Buffers: shared hit=10729
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.27..52523.53 rows=812 width=48) (actual time=759.898..14708.292 rows=10132 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (((agnt.code)::text = (txi.src_id)::text) OR ((agnt.code)::text = (txi.dest_id)::text))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 65321568
        Buffers: shared hit=10729
        ->  Index Scan using mjr_agent_pkey on mjr_agent agnt  (cost=0.27..189.56 rows=86 width=66) (actual time=0.045..1.827 rows=700 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=92
        ->  Materialize  (cost=1000.00..50911.10 rows=947 width=156) (actual time=0.001..5.658 rows=93331 loops=700)
              Buffers: shared hit=10637
              ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..50906.37 rows=947 width=156) (actual time=0.809..616.836 rows=93331 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 4
                    Workers Launched: 4
                    Buffers: shared hit=10637
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mjr_transaction_item txi  (cost=0.00..49811.67 rows=237 width=156) (actual time=0.150..625.545 rows=18666 loops=5)
                          Filter: ((txn_date >= (concat(((date_trunc('month'::text, to_timestamp('2019-04-01'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text)))::date - 1), ' 15:00:00'))::timestamp without time zone) AND ((concat((((date_trunc('month'::text, to_timestamp('2019-04-01'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text)) + '1 mon'::interval) - '1 day'::interval))::date, ' 15:00:00'))::timestamp without time zone >= txn_date))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 208542
                          Buffers: shared hit=47351
Planning time: 0.582 ms
Execution time: 14718.609 ms
```

**Hardware specifications**

Cent OS 7.6, Memory 32 GB , 8 CPU , Postgres 10.0

Average query execution time is around **12** seconds and this is not acceptable for my application. I don't have too much experience for database tunning and I am not quite good at writing SQL too. So , I'm requesting every suggestions from experience developers. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is looking pretty nasty, and is full of function calls.  You might want to add sample data, so that we can understand why you arrived your current query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the functions are only applied to constant values, so they will be evaluated once before the execution starts. They won't prevent usage of a possible index on `txn_date`

Comment: Which indexes are defined on the tables? One on `mjr_transaction_item (txn_date)` might help. But the `OR` condition in the join isn't really ideal to be supported by an index

Comment: Note that it's usually better to show us table structures as `CREATE TABLE` statements rather than screen shots. That way someone who wants to try out a solution can simply copy and paste the DDL and doesn't have to guess data types or index definitions.

Comment: Definitely try the index on `txn_date` and do not forget to run `analyze mjr_transaction_items;` to update statistics. To improve the OR condition of the join, you could try to create an index on the array of the two columns: `create index on mjr_transaction_item using gin (array[src_id, dest_id]);` then change the join condition to `on array[agnt.code] <@ array[txi.src_id, txi.dest_id]`

Comment: `OR` in a `JOIN` is usually a performance killer.  I would recommend asking a *new* question (you an delete this one).  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.  Also include your query, but there is probably a better way to write the query.

Comment: Unrelated, but you could make the where clause more readable with something like this:  WHERE txi.txn_date <= (make_timestamp(2019, 4, 1, 15, 0, 0) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') AND txi.txn_date >= (make_timestamp(2019, 4, 1, 15, 0, 0) - interval '1 day')

Comment: @Jeremy my date part `'2019-04-01'` is parameterized.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hello sir. I'm very sorry for late to reply because I got troubles installing `postgres-contribute` package to available for `pg_trgm` extension. Now I'm ready but create index query `create index on mjr_transaction_item using gin (array[src_id, dest_id]);` is not valid. The error show `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "array"`. I didnot found any similar query with that. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Sorry, that needs to be between parentheses `create index on mjr_transaction_item using gin ( (array[src_id, dest_id]) );` (but you don't need `pg_trgm` for that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow ! Yeah ... It is now drammatically faster than before. Thank you sir. Can you post as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (left) JOIN with an OR condition is usually not very well optimized. But what you can do is create an index on the [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) of both columns and then change the join condition to use an [array operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

First create the index:

```
create index on mjr_transaction_item using gin ( (array[src_id, dest_id]) );
```

Then change the JOIN condition:

```
...
FROM mjr_agent agnt
  LEFT JOIN mjr_transaction_item txi ON array[agnt.code] <@ array[txi.src_id, txi.dest_id] 
WHERE ...
```

---

You could also use an ANY condition, but I don't think that would use the index:

```
...
FROM mjr_agent agnt
  LEFT JOIN mjr_transaction_item txi ON agnt.code = ANY(array[txi.src_id, txi.dest_id]) 
WHERE ...
```